# Recuperar image de SQL Server desde Java

Tags: java, sql-server, imagen

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde lleno un formulario desde Java y los guardo en una base de datos en SQL Server, pero uno de los campos dentro de la BD es `image`.

Cuando inserto o guardo los datos se ejecuta perfectamente, pero cuando intento recuperar los datos o mostrar mediante un botón "buscar" no sé como mandar a llamar el campo que contiene el tipo de dato `image`.

Anexo el código del botón buscar:

```java
private void btn_buscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {

        //paso 1 cargar el driver
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        //paso 2 coneccion con la BD
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://EDDATZIN:1422;databaseName=BDALLMUSIC";
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "eddatzin", "eddatzin");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("Select * from CANCIONES where ID_Cancion = ?");
        pst.setString(1, txt_buscar.getText());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            txt_nombre.setText(rs.getString("Nombre").trim());
            txt_artista.setText(rs.getString("Artista").trim());
            txt_album.setText(rs.getString("Album").trim());
            //el contenedor donde muestro la imagen es un Jlabel por eso la nombre lbl_img

            lbl_img.setIcon(rs.("Portada"));

            String guardar = txt_buscar.getText();
            txt_id.setText(guardar);

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe la cancion." + "\nVuelva a intentarlo");
        }

    } catch (Exception er) {
        System.out.println("error en buscar " + er);
    }
}
```

**Les anexo mi interfaz del JFrame en Java NetBeans**
[image: JFrame]

**Y tambien mi tabla en SQL Server**

```sql
--CREAMOS LA TABLA "CANCIONES"
CREATE TABLE CANCIONES (
    ID_Cancion INT NOT NULL identity (1,1), --EL ID NO SE PUEDE REPETIR MUCHO MENOS IR VACIO
    Nombre VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL, --NO PUEDE IR VACIO Y TAMPOCO SE PUEDEN REPETIR NOMBRES
    Artista VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL, --NO PUEDE IR VACIO
    Album VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL, --INGRESAR EL ID DE LA TABLA ALBUM DE TIPO ENTERO
    CONSTRAINT UQ_Nom UNIQUE(Nombre) --EL CAMPO NOMBRE TIENE UNA RESTRICCION UNIQUE (NO PUEDEN AVER CANCIONES CON EL MISMO NOMBRE
)

ALTER TABLE CANCIONES ADD Portada image;
```

### **CODIGO ACTUALIAZADO YA CORREGIDO Y EN FUNCION**

Botón buscar:

```
//paso 1 cargar el driver
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            //paso 2 coneccion con la BD
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://EDDATZIN:1422;databaseName=BDALLMUSIC";
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "eddatzin", "eddatzin");
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("Select * from CANCIONES where ID_Cancion = ?");
            pst.setString(1, txt_buscar.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {

                txt_nombre.setText(rs.getString("Nombre").trim());
                txt_artista.setText(rs.getString("Artista").trim());
                txt_album.setText(rs.getString("Album").trim());
                lbl_img.setIcon( new ImageIcon(rs.getBytes("Portada")) );
                String guardar = txt_buscar.getText();
                txt_id.setText(guardar);

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe la cancion." + "\nVuelva a intentarlo");
            }

        } catch (Exception er) {
            System.out.println("error en buscar " + er);
        }
```

Comment: No hay ninguna columna con tipo de dato `image` en la tabla que publicas. Menos mal que es así, porque el tipo de dato `image` está marcado como obsoleto y [Microsoft recomienda que no se use](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) para desarrollos nuevos, para eso está el tipo de dato `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: Prueba con `lbl_img.setIcon( new ImageIcon(rs.getBytes("Portada")) );`

Comment: @jachguate si la agregue solo que la modifique al ultimo

Comment: voy  a probar con lo que me dices

Comment: Entonces actualiza tu pregunta con el código real, incluyendo ese campo. Puedes incluirlo en un alter table si así lo tienes, pero que se vea qué es lo que está...

Comment: @jachguate muchas gracias si me funciono